# A paper seems to mention a planar graph's "faces" in an embedding-less context

Tags: graphs

I am trying to implement the "DWR algorithm" described in Fig. 2 of [This Paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.41.3.572) (in order to get a program that reduces a planar graph to K2 using solely loop removal, leaf removal, "contraction" of nodes of deg 2, removal of redundant parallel edges, and, most importantly, delta-wye and wye-delta transformations)

The algorithm is [described as embedding-free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Nc5.png) (c.f. middle of the second column in p. 573)

However, p. 574, the algorithm's *Step 1* [requires one to find all edges sharing a face with some vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8KEw.png).

My beginner understanding of graph theory would declare this as impossible, as an edge might or might not share a face with a vertex depending on the embedding (something confirmed by the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185666/find-all-faces-in-a-graph-from-list-of-edges)).

I am asking how to solve this apparent contradiction.

- Did I completely misread the paper ? is there a way to do this without any embedding ?
- Or, is there an implicit embedding ? Some googling suggested that if there is one, it probably is the counterclockwise embedding.

Comment: @stef thanks ! What exactly is the difference between stackoverflow.com and cs.stackoverflow.com ? Aren't both dedicated to computer science ? Also, is there a rule against posting the same question on stackoverflow.com and cs.stackoverflow.com ? If so, would it be a good idea to delete this question and ask it on cs.stackoverflow.com ? (sorry to ask all these questions here but googleing just wouldn't help)

Comment: stackoverflow is about programming; cs.stackexchange is about computer science. Posting a question twice is not good; but deleting a question to repost it is not good either. Although it's possible to migrate the question, only a moderator can do that. I mostly mentioned it so if you ask another question in the future, you can choose the best site. For a programming question such as "how can I get the connected components of a graph with python?", stackoverflow is definitely best. For a theoretical question such as the one you asked, cs.stackexchange is better.

Comment: The main difference between the two sites is the community of users that browse it; you're more likely to get an answer if you ask on the appropriate site. Also, future readers who might be interested in your question and its answers will find it more easily if it's on the appropriate site.

Comment: Another important factor to help people find your question are the tags - you already tagged your question as graph-theory and planar-graph, which is great. There's also a tag called [embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedding) but without context, the meaning of that tag appears to be so broad that I doubt it's helpful.

Comment: thanks. So that means the best course of action is simply to leave this question here despite the fact it obviously doesn't belong here, and that it would attract fewer answers ? I mean, sorry to insist; but how would deleting this question and posting it again on cs.stackoverflow.com set back anyone else that would also come up, in the future, with the same question ?

Comment: I don't know. One reason is that there exists a "migrating" mechanisms, and that it's better to migrate rather than to delete then repost. In particular, any user who clicked "Follow" on your question will keep following it if it's migrated, but not if it's deleted than reposted. Also, any answer posted here would be migrated with it if it's migrated, but deleted with it if it's deleted. But since no one posted any answer yet, I suppose you could do that. Anyhow, I once suggested to someone that they ask their question on cs instead, and I got reprimanded and told never to advise that again.

Comment: So I will not advise you to delete your question then repost it on cs :-° Of course you could do it even if I don't advise it :-°

Comment: Thanks. By the way, i found the solution: the paper says it avoids <i>grid</i> embeddings, which is the problem of finding, if possible, a grid graph isomorphic to a given one. Doing so is tedious and was required by a previous paper (Truemper 1989) to solve the problem of delta-wye reducibility. However, the paper of the question does indeed requires embeddings; it talks about "plane graphs" which are planar graphs alongside an embedding. I am not from an english speaking country and thought "planar"="plane".